# Получаю ошибку при отправке формы (MERN-сайт)

Tags: reactjs, node.js

Создаю MERN-сайт по достаточно длительному [туториалу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxTeE5EMiWI&t=8039s) из YouTube.
Полностью закончил Front-end и Back-end регистрации.

Проблема: при попытке отправить форму получаю ошибку на экране: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message'),= TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')`,

а так же ошибку в консоли: `authSlice.js:48  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')`

Перепробовал все варианты, даже ChatGPT не был силён. Жду того, кто сможет объяснить, почему получаю ошибки при попытке отправить форму, и, желательно, исправит код.

Ссылка на проект: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/XU7o4-6oOQspTg